# Do I have to generate an output sample for each input sample?

Tags: video, filter, directshow

I have written a transform filter (a video codec) that works well in graph studio. It is targeted at a specific third-party application.

Unfortunately, it does not work so well in the third party application as it appears this application expects my filter to generate an output sample for every input sample received.

Before I enter into a discussion with the developers of said application I would like to confirm that there is no requirement in directshow for a one to one relationship between input samples and output samples (in this case video frames). I have not seen any indication of this in the documentation.

Is it possible that my filter could somehow be advertising that it does produce an output for each input? If so, how do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to, and there are filters that don't procude 1 output for 1 input, including among stock filters shipped with Windows (for example, [Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

There is no need or way to advertise this behavior, however you might be right (i.e. it's possible) that a top level application might be falsely assuming this and as a result act incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not required, because otherwise it would never be possible to create a filter which [changes the framerate](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/Multimedia/Filters/Filters/LEADVideoFrameRateControllerFilter%282.0%29_UI.htm) (some deinterlace filters do that too). However keep in mind some filters synchronising audio and video. So you have to generate some samples, and use a proper timecode.

Comment: This is a video-only application. I think the application has a fundamental flaw but I want to be sure.